# Plane tiling into rectangles of irregular sizes

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a grid of a fixed size. I'm trying to tile it into 
multiple rectangles of different sizes. 
The size difference is needed because I have to balance 
the content of each rectangles in order to parallelize
the process and have balanced threads.

The grid contains individuals, so some cases may be free,
others may contain different types of individuals.

I've been told to look into "Plane tiling algorithms" but
I can't seem to find anything or can't find the right term
for what I'm looking for.

Comment: what is the content of the rectangles? are you going to use the space subdivision to do optimized search operations for the rectangle contents?

Comment: the space subdivision is for optimized parallelism balance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to do space subdivision in order to have some kind of search operations up and running in a balanced way.

For that, there are [Quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) available, balanced [Binary Space Partitioning Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning), and [K-d trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

If you need optimized parallel space partitioning, there is a great article about parallelized Octree and a related library coming from [Uni Bonn, Germany](http://burstedde.ins.uni-bonn.de/research/papers/BursteddeWilcoxGhattas11.pdf) which is quite recent, and the library is open source.

Comment: Thanks, the quadtrees might be exactly what I'm looking for. Going to read more about it.

Comment: np! I'm glad it helped!